# Xamarin Forms - control the height of a button in a grid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Notice the two buttons below.  The first is in a StackLayout, and the second is in a 1x1 grid cell.  The first obeys the HeightRequest property, but the second will not.

How can I control the size of a Button inside of a GridCell?

[image]

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleApp"
             x:Class="SimpleApp.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Button" 
                HeightRequest="30" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Text="Button" 
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `<RowDefinition Height="200" />` to `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` to take in consideration your button size.

If you really want the row to have that size, simply set `VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"` in your button XAML code.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set `<RowDefinition Height="200" />` to `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />` if you want to set this to the default button height. as using `<RowDefinition Height="200" />` will take any unused space.